# Port forwarding to a computer with two NICs

Tags: wireless-networking, port-forwarding, network-adapter

I have a laptop which occasionally uses Ethernet and most of the time WiFi. Now I want to forward a port in the router so that it always points to my current IP. I'm likely to get different IPs from time to time and I can't really use a dedicated IP for the machine since the IPs are assigned by MAC address and the wireless card has a different MAC address than the Ethernet port.

I'm using a NetGear CG3100 router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What OS are you using?  In Windows you can [turn on UPnP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/941206) which should let you configure your router from Windows.  There also seem to be a bunch of tools that use UPnP to configure port forwarding on the fly.  [This page](http://www.fyxm.net/nat-port-forwarding-upnp-tool-95674.html) lists a bunch, and [this one in particular](http://www.fyxm.net/UPNP-Port-112076.html) seems promising.

Comment: I'm using Arch Linux, but it seems enabling UPnP in the router "just works". Thanks.